# Hibernate query Count logic

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public boolean minimoUmSuperUsuario(Usuario usuario, Session sessionExterna) throws HibernateException {  
Criteria crit = sessionExterna.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

return (Long) crit.uniqueResult() > 0;  

}
```

Heres what I need to do:

```
select * from usuario where superusuario and usuarioativo = true
if  superUsuario and usuarioAtivo == 1 return true 
else false.
```

I dont know how to put this in the method above

#### UPDATE

This is what i have done

```
public boolean superUsuarioUm(Usuario usuario, Session sessionExterna) throws HibernateException {
  Criteria crit = sessionExterna.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("superUsuario", usuario.isSuperUsuario()));
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("usuarioAtivo", usuario.isUsuarioAtivo()));

  final Number value = (Number) crit.uniqueResult();

  if (value.intValue() <= 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to execute the query and get the result.

```
 Criteria crit = // your criteria from your post

 final Number value = (Number) crit.uniqueResult();
 return value.intValue() <= 1;
```

Comment: I made a new post with the full code , can you check it?

Comment: There is no need to use an if-block as you can simply perform the test directly as in my code above and achieve the same goal without a branch operation.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get the result from database is use `crit.uniqueResult()`. This will give you a number of rows, but it will be an `Object`. You can cast it to `(Number)` and use `intValue()` method to get an `int`. At the end compare it to `1` and you're done! :)

Comment: thank you I made a new answer based on your and Naros answer can u take a look?